# vis.js Dynamically create a new item on a timeline

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I'm looking for a method to dynamically create new individual items on the timeline in vis.js

Looking at the documentation (http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/) I cannot see any method to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataSet.add` allows you to modify the data set after its creation. The example linked in the question has code like:

```
var items = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, content: 'item 1', start: '2013-04-20'},
    ...
    {id: 6, content: 'item 6', start: '2013-04-27'}
]);
```

This creates a [`DataSet`](http://visjs.org/docs/data/dataset.html). The examples on the `DataSet` page have this example using the `add` method:

```
var options = {};
var data = new vis.DataSet(options);

// add items
// note that the data items can contain different properties and data formats
data.add([
  {id: 1, text: 'item 1', date: new Date(2013, 6, 20), group: 1, first: true},
  {id: 2, text: 'item 2', date: '2013-06-23', group: 2},
  {id: 3, text: 'item 3', date: '2013-06-25', group: 2},
  {id: 4, text: 'item 4'}
]);
```